# sqlcipher how to import a sqlite3 database

Tags: database, encryption, sqlite, sqlcipher

I have dumped a sqlite3 database into a .sql file. Afterwards I have import the files like this:

`cat databasedump.sql | sqlcipher encrypted_database`

Then I've opened the encrypted database and set the key with:

`pragma key="12345"`

then I close the database and reopen it, it's still not encrypted.

How can I load the dump in the database and encrypt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sqlcipher plaintext.db
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY 'my password';
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');
sqlite> DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
```

Comment: This works, but how can I decrypt the database? Normally its `pragma key='my password';` but it's not decrypted afterwards I just get the following message: `Error: file is encrypted or is not a database`. I see only the similiar way back.. so attaching new databas.. decrypting.. selecting.. detaching.. etc. Is there a way to decrypt it and load it directly in ram?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ./sqlcipher encrypted.db
sqlite> PRAGMA key = 'my password';
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'plaintext.db' AS plaintext KEY '';  -- empty key will disable encryption`
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('plaintext');
sqlite> DETACH DATABASE plaintext;
```